# SQL- Find those countries that had both battleships and battlecruisers

Tags: sql

I have this small database example from an exercise.

```
## country           type  ##
1. Germany           bb
2. USA               bb
3. Japan             bc
4. USA               bb
5. Gt. Britain       bc
6. Gt. Britain       bb
7. USA               bb
8. The Netherlands   bc
9. Japan             bb
```

Now the question is:

> Find those countries that had both battleships and battlecruisers

I have thought about it but i can't seem to figure out how to approach this, since a simple AND function doesn't work.

Comment: Your database schema, OR rather table design is poor! There are several entries where USA is having bb values consistent.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Explain Column name? table name?

Comment: make this a crosstab and the 'simple AND' will work

Comment: `select country from t group by country having count(distinct type) > 1`

Comment: This isn't too hard to understand right? I have a table with country names and ship types. I want to select the countries that have both types of ships. So yea you see USA 2 times with bb, so that one i don't want but the Gt.Britain i do want. I don't know how to post the table nice aligned and all but it shouldn't be too hard to see right. I use R with the SQLITE library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `country` column and take only those groups having more than just one distinct `ship_type`

```
select country
from your_table
group by country
having count(distinct ship_type) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Just a followup question out of curiousity. This won't work anymore if there are 3 types of ships and i only want to check for 2 out of 3. What would you do then?

Comment: @NickW Just add `WHERE type IN ('bb','bc')`, or change the count to `< 3` depending on if you care which two types they are.  If you want specifically 2 types, and not 3, then the count becomes a case expression most likely.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach would be to filter down to countries that have one type, let's say `bb`, then filter those down to only the countries that also have `bc` with `EXISTS()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM yourTable yt1
WHERE type = 'bb'
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM YourTable yt2
            WHERE type = 'bc'
            AND yt1.country = yt2.country)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to compare rows of the same table, I think you should do a INNER JOIN.

Something like :

```
   select c.name from Country as c 
   INNER JOIN Country c1 
   ON c.name = c1.name
   AND NOT c.ship = c1.ship;
```

Comment: This also worked, then here too the question: If i have 3 types of ships: bb, bc and bd. How can i select the countries that only have bb and bc and not bd.

Comment: You can do multiple INNER JOIN as far as I know but I agree that it is not really elegant way to scale if your request want to handle N types of ships

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY country
HAVING MAX(CASE type WHEN 'bb' THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND MAX(CASE type WHEN 'bc' THEN 1 END) = 1
ORDER BY country
```